# Created a new table in SQL Server Express, running Windows 8.1, then tried to insert a record and got an error

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

```
CREATE TABLE Promotions 
(
     CSCFileNumberId INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
     SurName VARCHAR(30), 
     DateofFirstAppointment INTEGER, 
     InterviewScore INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO Promotions (CSCFileNumberId, SurName, DateofFirstAppointment, InterviewScore)
VALUES (1, Omereji, 098761, 45)
```

Error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Invalid column name 'Omereji'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Invalid column name 'SurName'.

Comment: Shouldnt `Omereji` be in quotes since it's a string?

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap literals with `'` and use `IDENTITY_INSERT`:

```
CREATE TABLE Promotions (CSCFileNumberId INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    SurName VARCHAR(30), DateofFirstAppointment INTEGER, InterviewScore INTEGER);

SET  IDENTITY_INSERT Promotions ON;

INSERT INTO Promotions (CSCFileNumberId, SurName,
                        DateofFirstAppointment, InterviewScore) 
VALUES (1, 'Omereji', 098761, 45);
                      -- leading 0 will be lost with INT datatype

SET  IDENTITY_INSERT Promotions OFF;

SELECT *
FROM Promotions;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2307f5c3f5706001bbae6507d20759c9)**

Comment: Table was created and record inserted successfully.